# How to sort this list based on age

Tags: python

How to sort this list of dict based on age using python

```
[{"age":10,"name":"a"},{"age":11,"name":"b"},{"age":10,"name":"c"},{"age":11,"name":"d"}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted()` and pass a `key` to denote that you want to sort by the `age` value in each dict.

```
data = [{"age":10,"name":"a"},{"age":11,"name":"b"},{"age":10,"name":"c"},{"age":11,"name":"d"}]

sorted_by_age = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['age'])
print(sorted_by_age)

#[{'age': 10, 'name': 'a'}, {'age': 10, 'name': 'c'}, {'age': 11, 'name': 'b'}, {'age': 11, 'name': 'd'}]
```